# How do I create thumbnails of pages similar to powerpoint on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I'm working on a project that is to essentially create the UI of PowerPoint with react. I have everything figured out except the left-hand side drawer that's on PowerPoint with thumbnails of every slide in the presentation.

How do I go about recreating this? One solution I can think of is to scale down every slide/page to fit within a 150px*50px div. However, I feel there has to be a more elegant solution.

The other idea I had was to use *html2canvas* to take a screenshot of the page and then resize the image. However, I feel this solution isn't scalable, as if I have over 100 slides then storing 100 images wouldn't be feasible.

Any ideas?